# Сколько баз данных должно быть в проекте с системой Identity? ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, asp.net-core-mvc

При добавлении в проект системы Identity создаётся стандартная база данных. Сколько должно быть баз данных в проекте? Одна, создаваемая системой Identity, и расширяемая дополнительными таблицами, или две (в одной содержится информация о пользователях и ролях, а в другой - прочие данные)? Что правильнее с точки зрения архитектуры приложения и безопасности данных?

Comment: Как вам удобнее, так и делайте. Можно вообще [разные](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dn818488.aspx) типы БД одновременно использовать.